# Independence of a couple of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three random variables (1-dimentional).

Is it true that $(X,Y)$ independent of $Z$  is equivalent to ($X$ independent of $Z$) and ($Y$ independant of $Z$).

X and Y are not independent.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $Z$ two-dimensional?

Comment: No: X,Y and Z are real valued random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid Bernoulli(1/2), i.e., coin flips $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2$.

Let $Z=(X+Y)\mod 2$.

Then $Z$ is independent on $X$ and $Y$ but not $(X,Y)$.

So, the answer is *no*.

Comment: Well done, thx. In wy work, i have to prove that $(p_1,\dots,p_q)$ is independant to $(X,u_1,u_n)$ conditionally to $u_1,\dots u_q$. Then it's not enough to prove it for $p_1$, then for $p_2$ ect...    :(